# Copy a dataframe column to another dataframe without the column header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe stockData (indexed by date):

```
stockData             BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  \
date                                                                            
2008-02-04               262.00               23397414             20875.7353   
2008-02-05               257.25               35213970             20497.5582   
2008-02-06               262.75               41323308             20935.7956   
2008-02-07               237.00              123276113             18884.0477   
2008-02-08               231.00               76456078             18389.9269
```

How can I copy one of the columns to another new dataframe without the column name? For example if I wanted the data for BBG.XLON.BT.A_LAST in a new dataframe (new_Df) indexed by date, I would like to see :

```
new_Df              
                                                                           
2008-02-04               262.00                 
2008-02-05               257.25                 
2008-02-06               262.75                 
2008-02-07               237.00                 
2008-02-08               231.00
```

Note there's no column name.

Answer (score 0):

Every column of a DataFrame has a name. You could set that name to an empty string, however:

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=list('ABC')); df.columns.name = 'stockdata'

In [55]: df[['A']].rename(columns={'A':''})
Out[55]: 
stockdata   
0          5
1          1
2          5
3          4
4          5
```

To also remove the name of the column index, `stockdata`, reassign `df.columns.name` to `None`:

```
In [56]: df.columns.name = None; df[['A']].rename(columns={'A':''})
Out[56]: 

0  5
1  1
2  5
3  4
4  5
```

---

To copy this column to a new DataFrame, simply assign it to `newdf['']`:

```
In [57]: newdf = pd.DataFrame()

In [58]: newdf[''] = df['A']

In [59]: newdf
Out[59]: 

0  5
1  1
2  5
3  4
4  5
```

Or, more succinctly,

```
In [60]: newdf = pd.DataFrame({'': df['A']})
```